# Window.print() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, printing

I have a question..I need to add an image when a push on the print button...For example of the top of the page I want to insert an image:
Print button:

```
  <li>
     <a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="window.print();return false;">Print</a>
  </li>
```

The print css:

```
#social-bar,#footer-copyright,#modal-reported,#modal-voted,#block-  user-container,#thevideoplayer
  {
display:none;
  }
```

Now,how I can to add the logo of company on the top?Help please

Answer (score 1):

Add image in page. hide for screen and show for print.

```
@media print {
      .printlogo{ // add printlogo as class for logo image
        display: block;
     }

}

@media screen{
    .printlogo{
        display: none;
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your print.css, make sure the logo container has `display: block` or is otherwise viewable.

Comment: but otherwise I could add a picture?